# What is the meaning of the javascript word this when it is used as an array?

Tags: javascript

I see statements like this inside a quojs javascript library:

```
return r(e,this[0].className)
```

or

```
return this[0].style[e]||n(this[0],e)
```

I know from the documentation that [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) refers to the "global object." But what does the array mean? The array of properties of the global object?

Comment: You have to track down the context. `this` depends on how the function is called, it's dynamic, and can be changed at runtime.

Comment: intereting question, heres another answer about what exactly 'this' might refer  to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133973/how-does-this-keyword-work-within-a-javascript-object-literal

Comment: From looking at the code though, I would say `this` is a NodeList.

Comment: The MDN documentation also explains which other values `this` can have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of `this` depends on many things, and you can't tell from that snippet of code.

For example:

```
var person = {
  name: "Bob",
  sayHi: function() {
    alert(this.name + " says hi!");
  }
};

person.sayHi();
```

In this example, `this` refers to `person` when the `sayHi()` method is invoked.  But If all I posted was this:

```
alert(this.name + " says hi!");
```

There would be no way to tell what the value of `this` is.  `this` is known as the *context*, so the context in which it appears is important!

Comment: what are the contexts in which this can take on the properties of an array?

Comment: When an array is the receiver of a method invocation. `myArray.foo()`, `this` is equal to `myArray` within `foo`.  But _any_ javascript object (which includes arrays) can be access with the `obj[key]` notation.