# Using "this" in a function in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to get access to `this` in a function, but it's undefined.

```
function processEachPath(element, index, list) {
    logger.debug(this);

}
```

...

```
_.each(config, processEachPath);
```

Comment: And what you expect to be in `this`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133973/how-does-this-keyword-work-within-a-javascript-object-literal/134149#134149

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to explicitly bind it to the function:

```
function processEachPath(element, index, list) {
    logger.debug(_this);
}

// ...

(processEachPath.bind(this))();
```