# Does 'this' inside an event listener always refer to the same object?

Tags: javascript, binding, event-handling, this

I'm not sure if this is a generic Javascript question: I'm using Appcelerator Titanium so there may be specifics for that platform.

Here is my question: if I add an event listener to an object, will the 'this' keyword in the event listener always point to the object?

**Example:**

```
var itemView = Ti.UI.createLabel({
    text: 'Dude'
})
itemView.addEventListener('click',function(e){
    alert(this.getText())
})
```

This example works. But maybe that's only because of some benign circumstance that doesn't always apply. My question is: can I rely on it to always work? Is the context for the event handler always the object to which the handler is bound?

Is that a fundamental Javascript law, and does Titanium / Alloy respect it?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should better look at this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133973/how-does-this-keyword-work-within-a-javascript-object-literal/134149#134149), I hope it might clear your confusion.

[***https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133973/how-does-this-keyword-work-within-a-javascript-object-literal/134149#134149***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133973/how-does-this-keyword-work-within-a-javascript-object-literal/134149#134149)

Comment: Thanks Yash. There's a lot of info there, but nothing specifically about 'this' inside event handlers. So I still don't know if using 'addEventListener' will always cause the this keyword inside the handler to point to the object to which the handler was attached.

Comment: It would make sense if it did, but nobody I can find is actually saying it.