# Javascript this keyword - inside function

Tags: javascript, this

I am trying to understand the `this` keyword on **Javascript**.

I was doing some tests on chrome console and I came across two different results that I was expecting to be the same:

```
var myTest = {};
myTest.test1 = function() {
        return this; // this = Object
}
```

This first function returns `myTest` object which I understand.

```
var myTest = {};
myTest.test1 = function() {
    return function test2() {
        return this; // this = Window
    }
}
```

Why is the second function returning the window instead of the `myTest` object?

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate, read this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133973/how-does-this-keyword-work-within-a-javascript-object-literal , also this article http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/08/30/understanding-javascripts-this/ and this http://unschooled.org/2012/03/understanding-javascript-this/

Comment: You aren't calling those functions, so [the `this` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) refers to nothing?

Answer (score 5):

`this` refers to the current object on which the function is called. When you called `test1`, you would have done like this

```
myTest.test1()
```

Now, `test1` is called on `myTest` object. That is why `this` refers to `myTest` in the first case.

In the second case, you would have executed like this

```
myTest.test1()()
```

`myTest.test1()` returns a function and you are invoking without any current object. In that case, JavaScript will make sure that `this` will refer the global object (`window` in this case).

**Note:** But, in strict mode, `this` will be `undefined`, in the second case. You can confirm that like this

```
var myTest = {};
myTest.test1 = function() {
    return function test2() {
        console.log("this is global", this === window);
        console.log("this is undefined", this === undefined);
        return this;
    }
}

myTest.test1()();
```

Output will be

```
this is global true
this is undefined false
```

But if you include `use strict` like this

```
"use strict";

var myTest = {};
myTest.test1 = function() {
    return function test2() {
        console.log("this is global", this === window);
        console.log("this is undefined", this === undefined);
        return this;
    }
}

myTest.test1()();
```

Output will be

```
this is global false
this is undefined true
```

Comment: It makes sense. Thanks a lot, that's exactly the missing point to me.