# Can someone please make me understand what is "this" keyword and its uses in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, this

I have tried the best resources, but can't understand a single thing. "this" is just so confusing, how does it connect with other variables outside. I have tried this source, everybody understands by that source but not me. Can anyone explain with superb examples. I am totally a begineer in Javascript.

This is the best source as they say.. 
[How does "this" keyword work within a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133973/how-does-this-keyword-work-within-a-javascript-object-literal)

Please help me understand "this". Really tired of searching all over the internet and books.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Comment: The post you linked claims to offer "more than you ever wanted to know about *this*". Is there something specific you don't understand? Or a specific application with which you're having trouble?

Comment: Kinda feel like if you don't understand the answer you linked to, you wouldn't understand anything else we could add to it..

Comment: @showdev I just dont understand why we need to use "this" ? .. Whats the purpose?

Comment: the purpose would be to access whatever `this` is bound to. It differs usecase by usecase.

Comment: @KevinB Yeah I knew this would be response. But I dont understand why we use "this"?

Comment: @KevinB .. Can give me examples of different uses ?

Comment: uhm... the answer you linked to gives 5.

Comment: No like what is importance? .. like this is where you would use "this" .. and this is where you would not ! .. or "this" makes it easy here for you and here not!

Comment: For example, in a click handler bound using addEventListener, `this` would be the element that was clicked (unless you used `Function.prototype.bind`). you can do stuff with said element, such as give it a class, add/remove events, change html, etc.

Comment: Oh ok . so we dont have to write .. document.getElementById("stuff") ? .. is this correct way i understood?

Comment: Correct. You would be able to skip that step because you already have access to the element.

Comment: Cool .. so is this the only use of "this" .. or it does hold some more powers? .. because it does seem a great keyword

Comment: In a nutshell, that is it's only purpose. however, how you apply that can differ widely, because event listeners are only one example of where you would have access to `this` defined to something useful.

Comment: Alright. Thank you @KevinB I got so mad that i was not able to understand "this" for so much long time. Today I wanted to get clear of this anyway! Thank you very much, I will dig deeper now with this knowledge

Comment: The first example in the answer you linked to. If `foo` had another method called `somethingElse`, you would be able to do `this.somethingElse()`, or if it had a property, such as `age`, you would be able to access it with `this.age` rather than going back to `foo.age`

Comment: but why ? .. we could have also written "foo.age".. is there any protection or security related things here?

Comment: `foo.age` is simpler in this case, but imagine if it was actually `foo.bar.baz.something.else.really.long.age` instead of `foo.age`. `this.age` would be far easier to use, and would work even if you moved it to another object entirely, as long as the properties were still there. using `foo.age` makes it far less reusable.

Comment: reusability .. yes indeed. I will have to practice using it only then i will be able to fully digest it. Thank you so much for this education. @KevinB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definition of the JavaScript this Keyword ? The object which called a function.

For example, you have an element that is a button. It has the value click me.
When you click on that button it will call the javascript function doSomething();

```
<input type="button" value="clickme" onclick="doSomething(this)"/>

function doSomething(ele) {
  // What we want to do, is change the text of the button.
  // To point at the button we use ele, which was passed in.
  ele.value = "Changed";
  // What we get is the buttons text changing to the word Changed
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: You'll need to pass `this` from the `onclick` function for this to work. [Example here](http://jsfiddle.net/yw9stemv/).

Comment: Fixed, saw this post on my way to bed, and just quickly answered.

Comment: @HarshalCarpenter Your welcome, feel free to up vote, and select as accepted answer.

Comment: I can't upvote but will accept :) .. You see i always ask idiot question so i get downvoted often :P .. but I can surely accept :)

Comment: *"The object which called a function."* is not a comprehensive explanation of `this`.

Comment: No its not I agree. However. By reading through the link the OP posted, that covers the comprehensive list. What the OP was asking for was a simplified explanation to get him started in javascript.

Comment: @BenTemple-Heald YES. Thank you for understanding. I have started to understand "this". Will have to work some examples from on my own to fully get the concept of "this".

Comment: I would say it's a *method* instead of *function*, since it is the correct term for a function belonging to/inheriting from an object.