# Trying to understand `this` in javascript

Tags: javascript, scope

I have an object with a number of functions:

```
var someScopeScopedObject = {
  myFunction1: function () {
    console.log('foo');
  },

  myFunction2: function () {
    this.myFunction1();
  }

 init: function (callback) {
    callback();
  }
}
```

So if I call `someScopeScopedObject.myFunction2` that works fine

But If I do `someScopeScopedObject.init(someScopeScopedObject.myFunction2)` then I get an error that `this.myFunction1 is undefined`

Why is `this` not valid when I call into the function that way?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does "this" keyword work within a JavaScript object literal?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133973/how-does-this-keyword-work-within-a-javascript-object-literal)

Comment: Its really not a duplicate

Comment: When you pass `myFunction2` as an argument to something, it loses the reference to the object it belongs to. `this` now refers to the function itself, and not `someScopeScopedObject`, hence your problem :)

Comment: This is also why some libraries take an object context for methods, ie. jasmine's `spyOn(someScopeScopedObject, "myFunction2")`, to keep the scoping correct.

Comment: @NielsAbildgaard thank you! thats the answer I was looking for, is there any good way around this?

Comment: @rogy Well I guess I should make it an answer then. You can do the same as jasmine... I'll post an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you pass `myFunction2` as an argument to something, it loses the reference to the object it belongs to. `this` now refers to the function itself, and not `someScopeScopedObject`, hence your problem :)

This is also why some libraries take an object context for methods, ie. jasmine's `spyOn(someScopeScopedObject, "myFunction2")`, to keep the scoping correct.

An example work-around (like the one used by jasmine) could look like this:

```
var someScopeScopedObject = {
  myFunction1: function () {
    console.log('foo');
  },

  myFunction2: function () {
    this.myFunction1();
  },

  init: function (context, callbackName) {
    context[callbackName]();
  }
}
```

This would allow you to do the following:

```
someScopeScopedObject.init(someScopeScopedObject, "myFunction2");
```

This is not the prettiest. Alternatively, you can bind the object to the function (so the scope stays the same). This assumes your original code in `someScopeScopedObject`:

```
someScopeScopedObject.init(someScopeScopedObject.myFunction2.bind(someScopeScopedObject));
```

Neither of these are pretty, and, really, that's because it is weird to *externally* feed a function belonging to an object as a callback to that object.

The best solution might be:

```
someScopeScopedObject.init(function() {
    someScopeScopedObject.myFunction2();
});
```

Answer (score 3):

The keyword `this` refer's to the functions scope. Not the global scope. You declare a function called `myFunction2`, the `this` refers to the scope of this function and not the scope in which this function is declared.

It isn't like in languages, like C#, where `this` refers to the current instance of the class, whether you are in one another method.

Answer (score 1):

`this` refers to the function in which it is declared,
So in your example,

```
var someScopeScopedObject = {
  myFunction1: function () {
    console.log('foo');
  },

  myFunction2: function () {
    this.myFunction1();
  }

 init: function (callback) {
    callback();
  }
}
```

myFunction1 is not declared inside myFunction2, so

```
` myFunction2: function () {
        this.myFunction1();
      }.
```

is not possible, because `this.myFunction1();` tries to call method myfunction1 which should be declared inside `myfunction1` which is not declared there.

> **Edit:**

1. `someScopeScopedObject.myFunction2();` is **possible** because you are calling the method myFunction1 which is defined inside `someScopeScopedObject`
2. `someScopeScopedObject.init(someScopeScopedObject.myFunction2);` is **not possible** because,  you pass `someScopeScopedObject.myFunction2` as a callback function in this case here to the init function,

`init: function (callback) {
    callback();
  }`

It then calls

`myFunction2: function () {
    this.myFunction1();
  }`

here you refer `this.myFunction1();`--- This doen not exist, since you are refering  to myfunction1 defined inside myfunction2, which is not!

Comment: So why does it work when calling it directly? but not through the `init`

Comment: `this` refers to the function in which it is used, if you are using `this.myfunction1` inside `myfunction2`, then you are trying to call methid `myfunction1` defined  inside `myfunction2`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/fajdoxgo/ im still not understanding why the first one works, and the second one doesn't

Comment: See in first one you are calling the` myfunction2` which is defined in the object `someScopeScopedObject `, and in your 2nd one you are not calling the same method, **because**, your `this.myFunction1()`, does not exist. because `myfunction1` is not defined inside `myfunction2` instead it is defined in `someScopeScopedObject`