# Javascript this.property undefined

Tags: javascript, object, undefined

I'm learning javascript and I can't figure out why this is not working?

```
var obj = {
   a : 10,
   b : this.a
}
```

The 'b' property is undefined. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133973/how-does-this-keyword-work-within-a-javascript-object-literal

Comment: here's a fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/4e39sufp/

Comment: Because you can't reference an object literal until it is created, one way to solve your problem is to use a variable: `var c = 10; var obj = { a: c, b: c };` or to create and then add properties: `var obj = {}; obj.a = obj.b = 10;`

Comment: Thank you! Much more clear now!