# Can I access properties of a scope object within itself using "this"?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, object, scope, this

I need to get the total of the following example:

```
$scope.fees = {
    basic: 1,
    premium: 2,
    total: this.basic + this.premium
}
```

Why won't this work? It says `this` is undefined. Is there a way to achieve this without having to write out `total: $scope.fees.basic + $scope.fees.premium`.

I'd love if there was a way to shorten it.

EDIT: I'd actually have to add the `total` property outside of `$scope.fees`. `$scope.fees.total = ...`

Comment: This question is very imprecise. It asks about "How to access", but clearly you know *how* - you just want to shorten it. So, are the answers to be judged by least amount of characters? Not to mentioned, that the entire question could have been asked without ***any*** reference to AngularJS or "scope" tags

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does "this" keyword work within a JavaScript object literal?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133973/how-does-this-keyword-work-within-a-javascript-object-literal)

Comment: Until the closing brace of fees is processed, $scope.fees does not exist yet and hence cannot be accessed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Why `this.basic` doesn't work

`this` is evaluated in the context of the function that contains this statement. So `this` doesn't refer to the `$scope.fees` object, but to the controller.

#### Why `total : $scope.fees.basic + $scope.fees.premium` doesn't work either

At the moment that the expression `$scope.fees.basic + $scope.fees.premium` is evaluated the `$scope.fees` object doesn't exist yet, because you're in the middle of creating it. Therefore it will result in an error like "Cannot read property basic of undefined".

#### How to solve this

There isn't any solution other than what you've already found that results in the behaviour you want, so unfortunately you'll have to stick with it.

Comment: Thanks, an explanation of how it works was best suited for me.

Answer (score 2):

You can use function ..

Hello {{ total() }}

```
function FeeController($scope) {

    $scope.fees = {
    basic: 1,
    premium: 2,

};

  $scope.total = function() {
    return $scope.fees.basic  + $scope.fees.premium;
  };

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using the "controller as class" pattern which lessens your dependency on the $scope.  You could do something like this:

```
app.controller('FeeCtrl', function () {
  this.basic =1;
  this.premium =2;
  this.total = this.basic + this.premium;
});
```

Then you can inject this controller right into your dom:

```
<div ng-controller="FeeCtrl as fee">   
 {{ fee.total }} 
</div>
```

There are more detailed  instructions here

**http://toddmotto.com/digging-into-angulars-controller-as-syntax/**

Comment: Yours is not a bad suggestion, but controller as or scope makes no difference here. If you substitute `$scope` for `this` in your example it is essentially the same. Though at least controller as could make things shorter, which seems to be the goal of the OP.

Comment: except since you aren't constructing an object literal, this.basic, etc is immediately available.

Comment: Yeah, I get that, but it would be the same with `$scope` as well. The point is that the object literal cannot be used the way the OP wants, not that controller as vs. `$scope` makes it behave differently, wouldn't you agree?

Comment: agreed, in fact the @Ramakrishna Kudikala answer is the closest to simply solving the problem, though I think that there's no reason for total to be a function.

Comment: True, but I do think your controller as suggestion is a good one. With angular 2 scope goes away, and unless you need to do emits or broadcasts, eliminating scope is a good thing IMHO.