# Scope of object literal methods

Tags: javascript, binding, scope, this, object-literal

I'm currently learning javascript and trying to understand 'this'. In the following code, why am I not able to access this.ul within my render method? (It says it is undefined). I was led to believe that the cacheDOM method would bind this.ul to the people object which could then be accessed by the rest of the Object.

```
(function(){

  var people = {
    people: ['Tom', 'Sean'],

    init: function() {
      this.cacheDOM();
      this.render();
    },

    cacheDOM: function() {
      this.input = window.document.querySelector('.input');
      this.button = window.document.querySelector('.button');
      this.ul = window.document.querySelector('.ul');
    },

    render: function() {
      var data = this.people;

      data.map(function(person){
        var li = document.createElement('li');
        li.textContent = person;
        this.ul.appendChild(li);
      });
    }
  };

  people.init();

})();
```

Fixed. Added `var ul = this.ul` into the top of my render function which then allowed the map function proper access!

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133973/how-does-this-keyword-work-within-a-javascript-object-literal) (no pun intended), may help shine some light on your situation.

Comment: Ah, all fixed :) thank you!

Comment: @Thomas_Hoadley How was it fixed?

Comment: defined `var ul = this.ul` at the top of my render function... which allowed the inner map function proper access! @hudsond7

Comment: `map` is creating a closure so `this` inside `map` will be `undefined` or in some implementations (jQuery) refer to `data` and not your outer object. Some implementation such as Lodash's `map` allow passing `this` into `map` as appended argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of **this** parameter  is determined by the invocation pattern.

There are four patterns of invocation in JavaScript: the
method invocation pattern, the function invocation pattern, the constructor invocation
pattern, and the apply invocation pattern.
Check [this link](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/javascript-the-good/9780596517748/ch04s03.html) to understand these patterns.

Check the following implementation of **render** function;

```
render: function() {
  var data = this.people;
  var that = this;
  data.map(function(person){
    var li = document.createElement('li');
    li.textContent = person;
    that.ul.appendChild(li);
  });
}
```

or you can pass the value of **this** as a an argument to the **map()** function :

```
  render: function() {
  var data = this.people;
  data.map(function(person){
    var li = document.createElement('li');
    li.textContent = person;
    this.ul.appendChild(li);
  },this);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Array.prototype.map method creates its own closure so that this won't refer people object here. You need to bind "this" to function as:

```
render: function() {
  var data = this.people;

  data.map(function(person){
    var li = document.createElement('li');
    li.textContent = person;
    this.ul.appendChild(li);
  }.bind(this));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can bind the function you are passing into `map` to the context of you object literal:

```
data.map(function(person){
  var li = document.createElement('li');
  li.textContent = person;
  this.ul.appendChild(li);
}.bind(this));
```

Or more transparently:

```
var iteratee = function(person){
  var li = document.createElement('li');
  li.textContent = person;
  this.ul.appendChild(li);
}
data.map(iteratee.bind(this));
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside the anonymous function *this* does not reference the object literal.  *this* is a reference to the owner of the scope where it is being referenced.  In an anonymous function I am pretty sure *this* is a reference to the global/window object.

To access the *ul* member of the object you can use the closure feature of JavaScript something like this.

```
render: function() {
  var self = this; // here this points to the object literal
  var data = this.people;

  data.map(function(person){
    var li = document.createElement('li');
    li.textContent = person;
    self.ul.appendChild(li);
  });
}
```