# Method error: Method name not defined

Tags: javascript, object, methods

Why isn't this code working? I'm trying to use the method to add up the properties and then assign the added up properties to its own value.

```
function howLongILivedSomewhere(college, home1, home2) {
    this.birthHome = 18;
    this.college = college;
    this.home1 = home1;
    this.home2 = home2;

    this.calcYearsAlive = function() {
    return birthHome + college + home1 +home2;
    };

    this.yearsAlive = calcYearsAlive();
}

var me = new howLongILivedSomewhere(4, 2, 3);

console.log(me);
```

Comment: use this keyword inside method or method call as well

Comment: @Venkatraman Thank You!

Comment: check my answer which has solution for you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed `this` keyword during your method / property call. Try like below.

```
  function howLongILivedSomewhere(college, home1, home2) {
    this.birthHome = 18;
    this.college = college;
    this.home1 = home1;
    this.home2 = home2;

    this.calcYearsAlive = function() {
      return this.birthHome + this.college + this.home1 + this.home2;
    };

    this.yearsAlive = this.calcYearsAlive();
}

var me = new howLongILivedSomewhere(4, 2, 3);

console.log(me.yearsAlive); // output: 27
```

#### What is `this` keyword?

A function's this keyword behaves a little differently in JavaScript compared to other languages. It also has some differences between strict mode and non-strict mode.

**Reference:**
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this
[How does "this" keyword work within a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133973/how-does-this-keyword-work-within-a-javascript-object-literal)

Answer (score 0):

Update the constructor to:

```
function howLongILivedSomewhere(college, home1, home2) {
    this.birthHome = 18;
    this.college = college;
    this.home1 = home1;
    this.home2 = home2;

    this.calcYearsAlive = function() {
      return this.birthHome + this.college + this.home1 + this.home2;
    };

    this.yearsAlive = this.calcYearsAlive();
}

var me = new howLongILivedSomewhere(4, 2, 3);

console.log(me);
```

Use `this` keyword when you need to access the object properties ([see here](http://rainsoft.io/gentle-explanation-of-this-in-javascript/#4constructorinvocation) more details).

Comment: Actually, that still didn't work. It gave me the Error message: calcYearsAlive is not defined.

Comment: You're right. Answer updated.

Comment: Awesome! It worked this time. Thanks for your help!