# How to reference base object properties from other objects using Object.assign()

Tags: javascript, prototype, mixins

I am trying to follow Kyle Simpson's idea of actual prototypal inheritance using only objects instead of functions. I wanted to see if I could use Object.create and Object.assign to add mixins to an object, which totally works. I then tried to take it a step further and base some of the values of the properties in a mixin on the value of a property in the base object. I always get NaN for the value I'm trying to work with. Here's the code:

```
function generatorFactory() {
    var basePlayer = {
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        baseHealth: 50
    };

    var generatePlayer = function() {
        return basePlayer;
    };
    return generatePlayer;
}

var playerGenerator = generatorFactory();
var basicPlayerObject = playerGenerator();

var heavyArmor = {
    defense: 15,
    attack: 9
};

var lightArmor = {
    defense: 7
};

var swordsman = {
    health: this.baseHealth + 10
};

var knifeFighter = {
    health: this.baseHealth - 10
};

var sigurd = Object.assign(Object.create(basicPlayerObject), heavyArmor, swordsman);

console.log(sigurd.health);
console.log(sigurd.defense);
console.log(sigurd.attack);
console.log("Player coordinates: (" + sigurd.x + ", " + sigurd.y +")");
```

I want to have the swordsman mixin adjust the player's base health. I tried using 'this', but it did not help. I'm starting to think I'm approaching this completely wrong. What exactly am I doing wrong here?

Comment: "*using only objects instead of functions*" - that doesn't make much sense. You're still using functions as methods, and by not using functions to create your objects you're loosing a lot of flexibility.

Comment: Could you unpack that a bit? I'm still learning this other way of working with prototypal inheritance,  so I may not be understanding or representing it correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the way you're using `this`. When you're defining an object, `this` still refers to the *surrounding* scope, not the new object you're defining:

```
var self = this;
var swordsman = {
    checkThis: self === this // true
};
```

One way of accomplishing what you're trying to do is to change those objects into functions.

```
function initSwordsman(obj) {
    obj.health = obj.baseHealth + 10;
}
var sigurd = Object.assign(Object.create(basicPlayerObject), heavyArmor);
initSwordsman(sigurd);
```

Comment: Okay, I see what you mean. 'this' referred to the global scope. I was hoping it wouldn't be evaluated until after the mixin was assigned to the base object, or maybe re-evaluated. I see why that doesn't work, though. Thanks, I'll accept the answer as soon as the timer on it runs out.

Answer (score 1):

The [`this` in your object literals](https://stackoverflow.com/q/133973/1048572) doesn't refer to what you expect. If you want it dynamically refer to the object the property is accessed on, you will need to use a getter:

```
var swordsman = {
    health: {
        get() { return this.baseHealth + 10; },
        enumerable: true,
        configurable: true
    }
};

var knifeFighter = {
    health: {
        get() { this.baseHealth - 10 },
        enumerable: true,
        configurable: true
    }
};
```

and you need to pass those property descriptors to `Object.create` instead of `Object.assign`:

```
var sigurd = Object.assign(Object.create(basicPlayerObject, swordsman), heavyArmor);
```