# Why IIFE this keyword refers to window object..?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

When I run the below IFFE, why does the `this` keyword refer to the `window` object and not to `a` variable?

```
var a = {
 printThis : function () {
 console.log('printThis', this);
  var inner = (function () {
    console.log('inner', this);
   })();
  }
};

a.printThis();
```

Result in the following output:

```
printThis **an object**

inner **window object**   <-- why..?
```

```js
var a = {
  printThis: function() {
    console.log('printThis', this);
    var inner = (function() {
      console.log('inner', this);
    })();
  }
};

a.printThis();
```

Comment: You are not calling `a.inner()`, just `inner()`. So `a` won't become `this`.

Comment: But it is inside a then too..

Comment: Doesn't matter. Every function gets their own `this`. If you want to keep the outer `this`, you have to use `bind` or `var self = this` or "fat arrow".

Comment: Can you please explain how this is working for JavaScript engine..?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does the "this" keyword work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

Comment: That is becomes `window` (the global object) is a legacy artefact. In strict mode, it will be `undefined`.

Comment: BTW - it's IIFE - Immediately Invoked Function Expression

Comment: Also have a look at [How does the `this` keyword work within a JavaScript object literal?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/133973/1048572) for why it won't refer to `a`

Answer (score 15):

Consider the following example:

```
var a = {};
var b = {};
a.hello = function() { console.log(this); };
b.hello = a.hello;
```

In most programming languages, `b.hello()` would print `a` since they base `this` on where the function is. The function is in `a`, so `this` is `a`. Makes sense, right?

However, JavaScript is a bit different in that regard. Instead of *where it is*, it's based on *how it was called*. `b.hello()` calls `hello` on `b`, thus `this` is set to `b`. This also makes sense since JavaScript doesn't really have a concept of "where" a function is (unlike methods in, say, Java, which are always tied to a specific class), and it's hard to determine that `a` is where it "is".

So, `foo.bar()` will always set `this` to `foo` for the purposes of this call to `bar` (unless one has used `bind` or similar to bind `this` to a specific value in advance).

Now, an IIFE is invoked on... nothing, really. It's not a `foo.bar()` situation, it's just a `bar()` where `bar` is your function expression. In cases like this where there's no `foo`, it defaults to the `window` object.

There are two simple workarounds:

1. Create a variable outside the IIFE containing the value you´re interested in: `var that = this;` and use `that` instead of `this` in the IIFE, or
2. `bind` the `this` value: `(function(){ CODE GOES HERE }).bind(this)();`

Comment: Before reading this answer, I was about to *flip this table in frustration*, but I couldn't figure out what *this* even was!