# this keyword reference in Javascript

Tags: javascript, this

Program:

```
<html>
...

<button class="accordion">Section 1</button>
<div class="panel"> <p> .... </p> </div>

<button class="accordion">Section 2</button>
<div class="panel"> <p> .... </p> </div>

<button class="accordion">Section 3</button>
<div class="panel"> <p> .... </p> </div>

<script>
        var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
        var i;

        for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
            acc[i].onclick = function(){
                this.classList.toggle("active");
                this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("show");
          }
        }
</script>
...
</html>
```

I am a newbie to javascript. So, I am not able to understand the above javascript code. I expect "this" keyword refers to
window object. Because, it is called within anonymous function and also there is no object for that function. But, it refers to the
object "HTMLButtonElement". How "this" refers to Button object ?

Comment: The `this` keyword is set based on execution context, which in this  case is an event handler, and event handlers has the element as context.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does "this" keyword work within a JavaScript object literal?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133973/how-does-this-keyword-work-within-a-javascript-object-literal)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How "this" refers to Button object ?

Every function has its own scope, its own `this` reference.

```
 acc[i].onclick = function(){
            this.classList.toggle("active");
            this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("show");
      }
```

This `function` is an event handler on `acc[i]` which is a `button` with class `accordion`. So, this is pointing to the DOM object pointing towards `HTMLButtonElement` pointing towards `acc[i]`

Comment: So, if the function is a event handler then "this" refers to the particular object which generates that event. Is it right?

Comment: @mrg yes, `this` will be the DOM object to which event handler is assigned.

Answer (score 0):

this keyword basically refers to the current object it is playing a role here as a event handler

Answer (score 0):

`this` refers to current `execution context` and in your case its button. If you want it to refer to `window`, keep a reference of it and then use it inside your `onClick` handler.

If you run the fiddle, you could see the results.

```
 var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
        var i; 
        var that = this;
        for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
            acc[i].onclick = function(){
                alert(this);
                alert(that);
                this.classList.toggle("active");
                this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("show");
          }
        }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/g1s0r9as/