# Value of this inside object method?

Tags: javascript, scope, arrow-functions

I very confusing about the value of `this` at the moment of an invocation function using arrow functions. Let's take my example:

```
var obj = {
  property: 5,
  func1: function () {
    console.log(this.property);
  },
  func2: () => {
    console.log(this.property);
  }
}
```

When i put this code on the browser console, an interesting thing happens, `func1()` will output `5` *as expected* *, but when i run `func2` i got `undefined`. What is going on here? Why the value of `this` inside `func2` makes reference to the global object(`Window` in this case).

I think i expect that output, because it is how it works, thats the reason why Alan and slevetman explains [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133973/how-does-this-keyword-work-within-a-javascript-object-literal#answer-134149) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13441307/how-does-the-this-keyword-in-javascript-act-within-an-object-literal#answer-13441628) respectively. But according to [the Jason's explanation](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/06/es6-in-depth-arrow-functions/)

> Arrow functions do not have their own this value. The value of this inside an arrow function is always inherited from the enclosing scope.

So, why the value of this inside `func2` is not inheriting the value of his enclosing scope `obj`?

Comment: It seems you understand how `this` behaves differently in arrow functions, but you don't understand how `this` behaves in general.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So, why the value of this inside `func2` is not inheriting the value of his enclosing scope `obj`?

The `obj` here is not the "enclosing" scope. The scope that you are defining the `obj` in is the "enclosing" scope.

Consider this example:

```
var obj = {
  property: 5,
  func1: function () {
      let func2 = () => {
        console.log(this.property); 
      }
      func2();
  },
}
obj.func1(); // logs 5
obj.func1.call({
   property: 6
}) // logs 6
```

When the inner `func2` is called, the `this` keyword refers to the `obj` as `this` in  the wrapper `func1` function refers to the `obj` and the `func2` *inherits* the `this` value. The inner arrow function does not bind it's own `this` value.

Comment: What you are trying to tell me is that the enclosing scope of the function is `Window`?

Comment: @Vohuman Curious why using `Function.prototype.call()` does not set `this` to `obj` at `obj.func2.call(obj)`? https://jsfiddle.net/pje0dtgn/

Comment: @Vohuman http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38557902/function-prototype-call-does-not-set-this-at-arrow-function

Answer (score -1):

The `this` in `func2` is inheriting the value of the scope of the function itself, no more. To make it work, you'll have to make something like that :

```
var obj = {
    property: 5,
    func1: function () {
        console.log(this.property); // shows 5
    },
    func2: () => {
        console.log(this.property); // shows undefined
        this.property = 6;
        console.log(this.property); // shows 6
    }
}
```