# Function.prototype.call does not set this at Arrow Function

Tags: javascript, arrow-functions

Note, Related [Value of this inside object method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38557764/value-of-this-inside-object-method/38557792#comment64506694_38557792)

Given

```
var obj = {
  property: 5,
  func1: function () {
    console.log(this.property);
  },
  func2: () => {
    console.log(this.property);
  }
}
```

`this` would be `Window` at `obj.func2()`.

When tried setting `this` to `obj` using `Function.prototype.call()`, `this` was still `Window`

```js
var obj = {
  property: 5,
  func1: function () {
    console.log(this.property);
  },
  func2: () => {
    console.log(this.property);
  }
}

obj.func2.call(obj);
```

1. Is this expected behaviour?
2. Why does `Function.prototype.call()` not set the `context` of
   `obj.func2` to `obj`?

Comment: `this` for arrow functions is captured from the outer context, so it is an expected behaviour.

Comment: @zerkms `Function.prototype.call`, `Function.prototype.apply` cannot set `context`:`this` of arrow functions?

Comment: Nope, http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-arrow-function-definitions-runtime-semantics-evaluation

Comment: This is by design. If you want functions where `this` can be re-assigned you MUST use regular functions. Regular functions may also exhibit this behavior if you use `.bind()`

Comment: [I essentially found a way to do this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61830943/1045881)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is expected as per [the standard](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-arrow-function-definitions-runtime-semantics-evaluation)

> An `ArrowFunction` does not define local bindings for arguments, super, this, or new.target. Any reference to `arguments`, `super`, `this`, or `new.target` within an `ArrowFunction` must resolve to a binding in a lexically enclosing environment.

That means - you cannot set something that is not defined.

Also, relevant:

The functions are called with the [`[[Call]]`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-ecmascript-function-objects-call-thisargument-argumentslist) internal slot that sets the `this` binding as

> 6. Perform `OrdinaryCallBindThis(F, calleeContext, thisArgument)`.

Which in turn [checks](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-ordinarycallbindthis)

> 1. Let `thisMode` be the value of `F`’s `[[ThisMode]]` internal slot.
> 2. If `thisMode` is lexical, return `NormalCompletion(undefined)`.

So, internally it has an additional check on whether the function is lexically scoped (an arrow function) or not.

References:

- [14.2.16 Runtime Semantics: Evaluation](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-arrow-function-definitions-runtime-semantics-evaluation)
- [9.2.1 `[[Call]] ( thisArgument, argumentsList)`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-ecmascript-function-objects-call-thisargument-argumentslist)
- [9.2.1.2 `OrdinaryCallBindThis ( F, calleeContext, thisArgument )`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-ordinarycallbindthis)