# Why setInterval not stopped by clearInterval

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var progressbar = {
    progress : null,
    html : function() {
        var loadingHtml = '<div id="loader-wrapper" class="catalog-loadmore">';
        loadingHtml += '<div class="progress"><div id="catalog-bar" class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" style="width: 10%"></div></div>';
        loadingHtml += '<div class=""><span id="progress-valuenow"></span>%</div>';
        loadingHtml += '</div>';
        return loadingHtml
    },
    start : function() {
        var width = 10;
        this.progress = setInterval(function() {
            $('#catalog-bar').css('width', width + '%');
            $('#progress-valuenow').text(width);
            if(width < 98){
                width += 1;
            }else{
                this.stop(); // this is not working
                clearInterval(this.progress); // this is also not working
                console.log('else')
            }
        }, 100);
    },
    stop : function() {
        clearInterval(this.progress);
    },
    destroy : function() {
        clearInterval(this.progress);
        $('#loader-wrapper').remove();

    }
}
```

In the above code, why the following statement not working the else condition is executed `console.log('else')` is printing but clearInterval() not working. I am calling progressbar.destroy() from outside and it is working.

```
this.stop(); // this is not working
clearInterval(this.progress); // this is also not working
```

Can any one tell me what i that i am doing wrong.

Comment: I'm not actually 100% sure, but this would only work in a class, and not in the inside of an plain object, or am I wrong here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does "this" keyword work within a JavaScript object literal?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133973/how-does-this-keyword-work-within-a-javascript-object-literal)

Comment: You're trying to reach `this.progress` while you're in another scope. `this` has another meaning there. You need to make a reference to `this` outside of `setInterval()` and use that variable.

Comment: @Bert Thanks this solved the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've passed anonymous function into `setInterval`, anonymous functions has context `this` setted to `window`, so you are targeting `window.progress`.

You have two ways to solve your problem:

- store `this` in some variable like

  `var _this = this;
  setInterval(function() { ... clearInterval(_this.progress) } ...)`
- use [`Function.prototype.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) to set context of your anonymous function like

  `setInterval(function() { ... clearInterval(this.progress) }.bind(this) ...)`

---

<sub>Or set up transpiler for ES6 and use [`Arrow function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) which binds `this` automatically</sub>