# In the following React code why the reference to the element is not returned?

Tags: reactjs, this

```
class App extends React.Component {
    method(){
        console.log(this);
    }   
    render(){
        return (<div>           
            <button onClick={this.method}>Try it</button>
        </div>)
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('demo'));
```

I think the button element is driving the method so the button element object should have been returned instead of `undefined`

Why so happens?Why you need to use this.method.bind(this) to have it worked?

Comment: Suggested reading http://blog.andrewray.me/react-es6-autobinding-and-createclass/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does "this" keyword work within a function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133973/how-does-this-keyword-work-within-a-function)

Answer (score 1):

when the function passed to `onClick` is called, it is called with the scope of the DOM element that was clicked, `this` is the DOM element. In order to get the `this` reference you want, you will need to create a new function which passes the reference as `this`. There is a handy built in method just for this, `bind`.
You can set up the bind in the constructor like so:

```
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor (props) {
        super(props);
        this.method = this.method.bind(this);
    }
    method(){
        console.log(this);
    }   
    render(){
        return (<div>           
            <button onClick={this.method}>Try it</button>
        </div>)
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('demo'));
```