# Using This in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, this

I have read over some rules to determine what the value of `this` is in different scenarios in Javascript. All was well till the example below threw me off.

```
function Person(name){
  this.name = name; //this is the object when function used as constructor (as expected)
  this.changeName = someFunction(); // produces error

  function someFunction(){
    this.nickName = this.name+"by"; //this is now the global object and not the instance, thus the name property does not exist.

  }
}

var a = new Person ('bob'); //error due to the function in changeName property.
```

From what I understood, the `this` variable takes up the value of the invoking object when called through dot notation or takes up the value of the newly constructed function when used with the `new` key word.

Can someone explain why the this statement in the function above is the global objet and not the newly instantiated object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can someone explain why the this statement in the function above is the global objet and not the newly instantiated object?

Because when you call a(n unbound) function as `func()`, `this` will refer to the global object (or `undefined` if the function is in strict mode).

Every function (except arrow functions) has its own `this` value. So the fact that you are calling `Person` as `new Person()` and that `this` inside `Person` refers to a new object, doesn't have any impact on the `this` value in `someFunction`. It only matters how you can `someFunction`.

You could call `someFunction` and explicitly set its `this` value via [`.call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call):

```
this.changeName = someFunction.call(this);
```

See also: [How to access the correct `this` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Comment: It answers why my implementation is incorrect. Thank you. I have already used the call() function in my fix when I realized it was the global object inside, but I needed a reason to know why it was the global object. This is the explanation I was looking for (Y).

Answer (score 0):

The `this` within `someFunction()` will reference a global object, because it's inside a function call. See a fuller, much more complete explanation at [How does "this" keyword work within a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133973/how-does-this-keyword-work-within-a-function)

If you wish to solve the issue, alias `this` inside the parent.

```
function Person(name){
  var self = this;  // Store a reference to the current instance  
  self.name = name; 

  self.changeName = someFunction(); // Odd that you'd capture the return value of a setter, ...

  function someFunction(){
    self.nickName = self.name+"by"; //self references the instance, creating the property.

  }
}
```