# Javascript - destructuring object - 'this' set to global or undefined, instead of object

Tags: ecmascript-6, this, destructuring

I have an object with two functions, `foo` and `bar`. `bar` calls `foo`.
Normally, this works fine when `bar` uses `this.foo()`. However, when destructuring the object, `this` doesn't refer to the object anymore. In the code snippet below, it is undefined. When I run this in chrome, it refers to the `window` object.

Expected output

```
func1()
foo
objectValue
foo
bar

func2()
foo
objectValue
foo
bar
```

Actual output

```
func1()
foo
objectValue
foo
bar

func2()
foo
globalValue (or Uncaught TypeError, in the case of the code snippet, which breaks here)
Uncaught TypeError: this.foo is not a function (in the case of chrome, which breaks here)
```

*note : to reproduce in chrome, change `let val = 'globalValue'` to `val = 'globalValue'`

```js
let val = 'globalValue'

let functions = {
    val : 'objectValue',
 foo : function(){
  console.log('foo')
 },
 bar : function(){
  console.log('this.val: ' + this.val)
  this.foo()
  console.log('bar')
 }
}

class Class {
 func1(functions){
  console.log('func1()')
  functions.foo()
  functions.bar()
 }
 
 func2({foo, bar}){
  console.log('func2()')
  foo()
  bar()
 }
}
let instance = new Class()

instance.func1(functions)
console.log('\n')
instance.func2(functions)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Destructuring is the same as assigning a property to a local variable. I.e. in your case it would be the same as

```
var foo = functions.foo;
var bar = functions.bar;
```

Functions are not bound to their "parent" object. What `this` refers to depends on how a function is called. `foo()` and `functions.foo()` are two different ways of calling a function, hence `this` has a different value in each case.

This nothing new to ES6 or destructuring, JavaScript has always worked like that.

See [How does the "this" keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3127429/218196) .