# Javascript cannot call THIS in code

Tags: javascript

I'm am using module js syntax and I have some code like this:

```
var myModule = {

    settings: {
        myage: 25
    },

    init: function() {

        //init code here

    },

    someFunction1: function(param1) {

        //function code here

    },

    someFunction2: function() {

       myModule.someFunction1(myparam);

    }

}
```

The above will work fine but if I tried:

```
someFunction2: function() {

    this.someFunction1(myparam);

}
```

It will not find the function.

Can't I use this.someFunction1... ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does "this" keyword work within a function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133973/how-does-this-keyword-work-within-a-function)

Comment: Show us how you are calling `someFunction2`

Comment: From outside I'm calling it like this: myModule.someFunction2(); From inside I just thought you could do this.someFunction2(); but apparently you can't ?

Comment: @JakeBrown777 No, if from outside you always call the methods on the module, then inside you should be able to use `this`. It appears there is a call somewhere in your code where you don't use `myModule.someFunction2()`. It might help to post a [MCVE] based on your real code

Comment: The only place where I use THIS is in INIT function to access the settings where I use: this.settings.myage which works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this` is who called the function.

`myModule.someFunction2()` will have this=myModule

`someFunction2 = myModule.someFunction2; someFunction2()` will have this=window

(you didn't show how you're calling it though)

Comment: From outside I'm calling it like this: myModule.someFunction2(); I just thought that once you are inside you could just use this that's all