# Method return undefined

Tags: javascript

I have a problem receiving a value from a void method

For example:

```
test() {
    var x = this.test2("hi there");
    console.log(x);
}

test2(data){
    return data;
}
```

I want to receive the data from `test2` but it keep saying `undefined` what do I do wrong in here? And how can I make this work?

It is probably so basic but I just want to know why I receive the value `undefined`

Comment: Any error? Or the log is `undefined`?

Comment: That code's looking just fine.

Comment: the log is undefined

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does “this” keyword work within a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133973/how-does-this-keyword-work-within-a-function)

Comment: You should also include the word `function` before the function name. `function test() { ` and `function test2() { `

Comment: Please post a complete example, with the whole object literal/class and the invocation of the `test` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `function` in front of definition.

```js
function test() {
    var x = this.test2("hi there");
    console.log(x);
}

function test2(data) {
    return data;
}

test();
```

Comment: …and remove `this.`, or what?

Comment: this worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Try like this :

```
test(): void {
    var x = this.test2("hi there")
    console.log(x);
}

test2(data): void {
    return data
}
```

Comment: That's not JavaScript.