# Error: Invalid value of type string for mapStateToProps argument when connecting component ConnectedForm

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm having a from adding article and following is the form

components/form.js

```
                import React ,{ Component } from 'react';
            import {connect} from 'react-redux';
            import uuidvl from 'uuid';
            import { addArticle } from '../actions/index';
            const mapDispatchtoProps= dispatch=>{
                return{
                    addArticle:article =>dispatch(addArticle(article))
                };
            };
            class ConnectedForm extends Component{
                constructor(){
                    super();
                    this.state={
                        title:''
                    }
                }
                handleChange(eVal,nm){
                    this.setState({[eVal.target.id]:eVal.target.value})
                }                    
                handleSubmit(ev){
                    ev.preventDefault();
                    const { title }=this.state;
                    const id = uuidvl();
                    this.props.addArticle({ title , id });
                    this.setState({title:''});
                }                    
                render(){
                    const {title}=this.state;
                    return(
                        <div>
                            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}>
                                <input type='text' value={title} id="title" onChange={(e)=>this.handleChange(e.target.value,'article')}/>
                                <button type="submit">Add</button>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    );
                }
            }
            const Form =connect('null',mapDispatchtoProps)(ConnectedForm);//**1**
            export default Form;
```

components/list.js

```
            import React from 'react';
            import { connect } from 'react-redux';
            const mapStateToProps=  state =>{
                return { articles :state.articles};
            }
            const connectedList = ({ articles }) =>(
                articles.map(e=>(
                    <li key={e.id}>{e.title}</li>
                ))
            );
            const List= connect(mapStateToProps)(connectedList);////**2**
            export default List;
```

I'm getting this error

**Error: Invalid value of type string for mapStateToProps argument when connecting component ConnectedForm.**

src/index.js

```
   <Provider store={store}>
    <Router>
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={App}/>
            <Route path="/components/Form" component={Form}/>
        </Switch>
    </Router>
  </Provider>
```

Can anyone please lemme know where I'm going wrong
?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass `null` as a keyword without the quotes as `connect` API checks for an object. As you passed  string, type validation present in the API implementation threw the error :

```
const Form =connect(null,mapDispatchtoProps)(ConnectedForm);
```

Comment: can u please explain about connect and why is it null?And mapDispatch is second parameter not first?

Comment: @Tested : The connect method from `react-redux` expects `mapStateToProps` as the first parameter and `mapDispatchtoProps` as the second. The order is important as there is no other way to distinguish which is which as both return objects and its generally a best practice to specify the order of arguments in the API. If you do not have `mapDispatchtoProps`, then you can simply call like `connect(mapStateToProps)(ConnectedForm)`. But if you do not have `mapStateToProps`, you need to pass the first parameter as null, to indicate the second parameter being passed is `mapDispatchToProps`.

Comment: @Easwar: could you please explain me what does this `this.props.addArticle({ title , id });` means. What is this notation here refers to. what is name of this notation of passing argument. Sometimes, ES6 notation confuse a lot.

Comment: `this` here refers to the component's instance as in the render method `onSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}>` binds `handleSubmit`. For more info please read : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133973/how-does-this-keyword-work-within-a-function