# Does an IIFE's this always point towards the global object?

Tags: javascript, function, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5, iife

I have a code snippet down below.

```
var obj = {
 name: "Mohit",
 func: function(){
  var self = this;
  (function(){
    console.log(this.name);
    console.log(self.name)
  })()
 }
}
```

After executing obj.func(), I get the first console.log to be undefined while I get the second one to be Mohit.

Does this mean that an IIFE always binds the this to the global window object?

How defining self to be this is the binding for the IIFE happening to the obj?

Comment: No, it depends on how you execute it. `(function() {}).call({ hello: "world" })` is an IIFE but `this` would be `{ hello: "world" }`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/133973/9867451

Comment: You can use an arrow function which doesn't have its own `this` so it will use the surrounding `this`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does the "this" keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

Comment: @VLAZ How does declaring var self = this binds the IIFE to the obj context?

Comment: @MohitKamal it doesn't *bind* it, it just ensures that the reference used within is the same as the `this` that is outside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Any* function you call without a clear reference for `this` will have `this` set to the global object, or in "strict" mode to `undefined` (which is not the case in your example).

You could explicitly ensure that `this` is bound to `obj` if you wanted:

```js
    var obj = {
     name: "Mohit",
     func: function(){
      var self = this;
      (function(){
        console.log(this.name);
        console.log(self.name)
      }).call(this)
     }
    }
    obj.func();
```

By using `.call(this)`, you provide a value for `this` inside the called function.

Comment: So let me get this straight, my code has an IIFE which is getting executed without any context binding. So, in this case, my IIFE will automatically get bound by the global window object?

If my IIFE was binded by some context with call or apply, it''s context would be the argument passed in the call/apply?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Any function, *any* function, that is called without on object reference will have `this` bound to the global object or, in "strict" mode, to `undefined`. Whether it's an IIFE or not does not matter.