# json recursive function does not send back complete Json Object

Tags: javascript, json, recursion, nestjs

I have the following JsonObject

```
let jsonObject = {
  "augmentedReality": {
    "enabled": false,
    "augmentedRealitySettings" : [
      {
        "assetId": 7
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I am have written a recursive function that looks the following

```
 isAssetId(jsonObject: any) {

for (let key in jsonObject) {

  if (typeof jsonObject[key] === "object") {

    jsonObject[key] =  this.isAssetId(jsonObject[key]);

  } else {
   
    if(key=='assetId'){
      jsonObject[key]=3;

    }} }

return jsonObject;

}
```

My goal is to change the assetId wherever it exists in the jsonObject. This JSON is just an example, while assetId could be far in the deeper.
The problem with the code is that when it's successfully executed it returns the following JSON object
I call the function with the following:

```
jsonObject=  isAssetId(jsonObject);

console.log(jsonObject);
```

and I get the following results.

```
  {
  augmentedReality: { enabled: false, augmentedRealitySettings: [ 
  [Object] ] }
   }
```

The `Object` should show the data it has not the object.
I cannot figure out what seems to be the problem. Any help would be appreciated?

UPDATE:
I wrote the code into the following site
[here](https://jsfiddle.net/3jgchot2/1/)
Weirdly it's working fine here, but it does not work on my typescript on `NestJs`? Now what is the reason?

Comment: Why are you using wait?

Comment: I removed it. Problem remains the same.

Comment: I dont think there is any problem with the code, that is exactly what should be returned from the function. What are you expecting in the result? if it is [[Object]] thing bothering you then just use JSON.stringify() while printing on the console.

Comment: @ShafqatJamilKhan when I stringify it I get ther following output
`{"augmentedReality":{"enabled":false,"augmentedRealitySettings":[{}]}}
`

Comment: Please check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is something wrong with the logic of your code. At one point you are looping through an array like an object. You could do something like:

```
var json = isAssetId(jsonObject);

console.log(JSON.stringify(json));

function isAssetId(jsonObject) {

for (let key in jsonObject) {

  if(Array.isArray(jsonObject[key])){
          for (const [i ,element] of jsonObject[key].entries()) {
           jsonObject[key][i] =  isAssetId(element);
      }
  }

  else if (typeof jsonObject[key] === "object") {

  jsonObject[key] =  isAssetId(jsonObject[key]);

  } else {

     if(key=='assetId'){
  jsonObject[key]=3;

}} }

return jsonObject;

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the correction. However, my issue remains the same when I execute it on `NestJs`

Comment: Thank you it works just fine. However, I don't want a strigify result, I need JSON object. So When I parse back like 
     `const finalObject= JSON.stringify(result);`
    `console.log(JSON.parse(finalObject));`
I get the same output with `object`. any idea here?

Comment: @ahmedali this is normal behavior for showing the results when you use console.log() essentially it will work just fine when you try to access that property in the parsed JSON.

Comment: Thanks a lot, everything seems fine.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is "this" keyword in the function. For more information please check [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133973/how-does-this-keyword-work-within-a-function).

```
let jsonObject = {
  "augmentedReality": {
    "enabled": false,
    "augmentedRealitySettings" : [
      {
        "assetId": 7
      }
    ]
  }
}


var json = isAssetId(jsonObject);

console.log(JSON.stringify(json));

isAssetId(jsonObject) {

for (let key in jsonObject) {

  if (typeof jsonObject[key] === "object") {

    jsonObject[key] =  isAssetId(jsonObject[key]);

  } else {
   
    if(key=='assetId'){
      jsonObject[key]=3;

    }} }

return jsonObject;

}
```

Comment: I am sorry I didnt get the heading of your question. which keyword is the problem?

Comment: NestJs cannot have function starting with the `function`

Comment: use isAssetId(jsonObject[key]); instead of this.isAssetId(jsonObject[key]);

Comment: you can remove the function keyword as well. let me update my answer

Comment: if I use `isAssetId` instead of `this.isAssetId` it returns an error.

Comment: can you share your nestjs script?