# how can create function anonymous javascript whit arguments this

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to perform an anonymous function with a this-type argument, with the aim that an element of DOM can occupy it.

javascript: (this is dynamically created at run time)

```js
const example = function(this) { return this }
```

html:

```html
<button onclick="example(this)" ><button>
```

result:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'this'

how can I do it?, thanks!

Comment: `this` is a special "argument" that you don't list as parameter. The value of `this` is determined by the caller of the function. Not sure what you mean with "doom". See [how does the `this` keyword work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133973/how-does-this-keyword-work-within-a-function)

Comment: "*a this-type argument, with the aim that an element of doom can occupy it.*" - what? Please show us how you intend to call that `example` function.

Comment: @trincot I think "doom" is a typo for "DOM"

Comment: Yeah, `this` is a reserved keyword in JS.

Comment: @Barmar `<marquee />` <- *element of doom*.

Comment: _"an element of doom"_... the `<center>` cannot hold

Comment: edited the question, thanks for answering, sorry for the bad writing, it's my first question and I don't speak much English

Comment: The example function does not suppose to get this, but an argument that will be the this (probably an extended of HTMLElement)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, `this` is a special keyword in JavaScript; when you call an object method, `this` contains the object that the method was called through.

Just use another variable name.

```js
const example = function(el) { console.log(el.innerText); };
```

```html
<button onclick="example(this)" >Click me</button>
```

Comment: thank you very much, but the element is created dynamically, I added more information, thank you very much for answering me anyway =)

Comment: See the updated answer.