Current User Implementation in Javascript
I'm trying to keep in track of current user of an request across my javascript code base and some data along with it within that request scope
I tried to
pass the current user from controller(read from request object) to service layer(s),
Expectation:
Instead I'm trying to have this currentUser exported to an object with some data where any service at any point within that request scope can use this variable and post the request ends this object destroys and serves for next request with respective user like wise.
// ./Controller/PlanController.js
module.exports.createPlan(request, reply) => {
   globalRequestAccessor.setCurrentUser(request.session?.user);
   //...some business code
   reply(PlanService.create({}));
}

// ./Service/PlanService.js
const create = async(object) {
  const user = globalRequestAccessor.getCurrentUser();
  return {};
}

my code base is built on Hapi framework. I'm trying to make this work for any number of concurrent request where on request the respective request-user can be looked, by any service or util or helper or any file under nested depth traced from service call, within the request scope. Kindly suggest your input on to make this work ?. Thanks

It's not totally clear what you're trying to do and what your services are. Do you want to access request.session.user
anywhere? Generally you'd just pass where you need it, and that's it, even with nested calls

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

If I understand your question correctly you don't want to use the request object to store currentUser and whatever other details, but you want a kind of static method to access current user, correct?

I think you are suggesting something like a ThreadLocal in java, which is not possible in js. You can instead do one of the following.
[Recommended] 1. Just pass the request/context object.
// ./Controller/PlanController.js
module.exports.createPlan(request, reply) => {
   let context = request.context;
   //...some business code
   reply(PlanService.create(context));
}

// ./Service/PlanService.js
const create = async(context) {
  const user = context.getCurrentUser(); // or context.user
  return {};
}

2. Similar to ThreadLocal but still need the request/context object
// ./Controller/Context.js
module.exports.getCurrentContext(request) => {
    return globalContextMap[request];
}

// ./Controller/PlanController.js
module.exports.createPlan(request, reply) => {
   //...some business code
   reply(PlanService.create(request));
}

// ./Service/PlanService.js
const create = async(request) {
  let context = Context.getCurrentContext(request)
  const user = context.getCurrentUser(); // or context.user
  return {};
}

3. Exploiting the this keyword
Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/134149/5588450
// ./Controller/PlanController.js
module.exports.createPlan(request, reply) => {
   let context = request.context;
   //...some business code
   let res = PlanService.create.call(context);
   reply(res);
}

// ./Service/PlanService.js
const create = async() {
  const user = this.currentUser;
  return {};
}

